# Will spark lazy execution lead to list override?

Tags: pyspark, lazy-evaluation

My question is will `quantile_foo` and `quantile_bar` be the right value passed to each loop?
Will the value of `quantile_foo` and `quantile_bar` be set to last time, that is, `i=5`, in the loop because of spark lazy execution, so that I always get wrong `foo_quantile_{i}` except for `foo_5`?

```py
df = spark.sql("select * from some_table")
for i in range(5):
    quantile_foo = df.approxQuantile("foo_{}".format(str(i)),[0.25,0.5,0.75],0.05)
    quantile_bar = df.approxQuantile("bar_{}".format(str(i)),[0.25,0.5,0.75],0.05)
    
    df = df.withColumn("foo_quantile_{}".format(str(i)),
                                  F.when(F.col("foo_{}".format(str(i))>quantile_foo[0],75))\
                                   .when(F.col("foo_{}".format(str(i))>quantile_foo[1],50))
                                        ... ...
                 )
    df = df.withColumn("bar_quantile_{}".format(str(i)),\
                                  F.when(F.col("bar_{}".format(str(i))>quantile_foo[0],75))\
                                   .when(F.col("bar_{}".format(str(i))>quantile_foo[1],50))
                                        ... ...
                 )
```

Comment: you aren't assigning the `df.withColumn("foo_quantile_{}" ...` to a variable. so, it isn't saved at all

Comment: Sorry I have fixed it now

Comment: based on the updated code -- lazy eval won't affect column creation. iter 1 -- `quantile_foo` has percentiles for `foo_0` which is used in `foo_quantile_0` creation. iter 2 -- uses `foo_1`. and so on. [`df.approxQuantile()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-approxquantile) returns a list (collected result), not a dataframe. so, the percentiles are evaluated at the beginning and you use the evaluated results

Answer (score 0):

I would say the answer to your question is Yes, it would take the last value of i to perform the operation but that has nothing to do with spark lazy evaluation.

You are assigning a different value to a variable in python and as it is in for loop, whenever you come out of the for loop you will get the last value.

Comment: I think what you  say is in converse of what @samkart days. I think the result would be right because evaluated list is passed to each loop. And maybe he is right?